# Powershell Register-ScheduledTask at creation/updation of task

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am looking for an option to run task as soon as it's created/updated.

This option is available in the Task Scheduler UI but I am unable to find the same in [New-ScheduledTaskTrigger](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649821(v=wps.630).aspx). How do I achieve the same using Powershell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a [`RegistrationTrigger`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382110(v=vs.85).aspx), which - as I know - can't be simply created using `New-ScheduledTaskTrigger`. But it can be created using [`Get-CimClass`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/powershell/windows/cimcmdlets/get-cimclass):

```
$trigger = Get-CimClass "MSFT_TaskRegistrationTrigger" -Namespace "Root/Microsoft/Windows/TaskScheduler"
```

---

**Additional information:**

As the help told us, we can pass multiple triggers with `-Trigger`:

> ```
> -Trigger [<CimInstance[]>]
>     Specifies an array of one or more trigger objects that cause a scheduled task to start.
> ```

Which means, that the following will create a task which is executed immediately after creation and after every <strike>update</strike> *registration:*

```
$trigger1 = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Daily -DaysInterval 1 -At 01:00
$trigger2 = Get-CimClass "MSFT_TaskRegistrationTrigger" -Namespace "Root/Microsoft/Windows/TaskScheduler"
New-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Trigger @($trigger1, $trigger2) -Description "Beschreibung" -Settings $settings -Principal $principal | Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName "test"
```

Now - when exporting the created task to an xml file, it will look like the following:

```
<Task version="1.3" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
    <RegistrationInfo>
        <Description>Beschreibung</Description>
        <URI>\test</URI>
    </RegistrationInfo>
    <Triggers>
        <RegistrationTrigger>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
        </RegistrationTrigger>
        <CalendarTrigger>
            <StartBoundary>2017-08-22T01:00:00+02:00</StartBoundary>
            <Enabled>true</Enabled>
            <ScheduleByDay>
                <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>
            </ScheduleByDay>
        </CalendarTrigger>
    </Triggers>
    <Principals>
        <Principal id="Author">
[...]
```

Comment: I don't see an option for `CreateOrUpdate` type trigger